# Material.io scss import doesn't work

Tags: sass, material-components-web

I am now creating html project using sass and client requested to use material.io web component. My sass is working fine. I included material.io component through node_modeules folder. But when I tried to access material-components-web.scss like below code

```
//style.scss file
@import 'layout';
@import 'typo';
@import 'image';
@import 'overwrite';
@import "~material-components-web";
```

I got this error message in style.css file.

```
/*
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: ~material-components-web.
       Load paths:
         /Users/kenvsi/www/static/mycondo/assets/sass
         /Applications/Koala.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/rubygems/gems/compass-core-1.0.1/stylesheets
         Compass::SpriteImporter
        on line 5 of /Users/kenvsi/www/static/mycondo/assets/sass/style.scss

1: @import 'layout';
2: @import 'typo';
3: @import 'image';
4: @import 'overwrite';
5: @import "~material-components-web";
```

My question is that I would like to assess all material scss components, variable and function to my custom scss file. Is there any ways to access those material scss options in html project?

Answer (score 0):

i think you miss to include the scss file.

I am using this with webpack for sass compiling.

`@import "~material-components-web/material-components-web";`

First "material-components-web" is a folder and second is a scss file.